# Handling Datetime as String in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, string, datetime

I want to search for a date in my database via ajax on each key pressed.
The format of the date which is typed into the input field is d.m.Y (german format).

So if I enter "26.1" into the search field, i want to get search results like 26.10.2016, 26.11.2091, 26.12.1985 etc. 
My idea: Turning the datetime into a string and comparing the input string with the database.

How can I handle the datetime field as a string? Is that even possible?

THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

You can easily manage date as string and convert in date using  str_to_date eg:

```
str_to_date('26.10.2016' , '%d.%m.%Y')
```

or

```
str_to_date('10/26/2016' , '%m/%d/%Y')
```

the result is a proper date value ..(nb remember of use the proper pattern)

use the proper pattern mean that if you use 26.10 thn you should use

```
str_to_date('26.10' , '%d.%m')
```

Comment: That works, if you type in the complete date like "26.10.2016", but won't show records if you just type in "26.10." e.g.

Comment: Thanks! But, that doesn't work for the input "26.1" either. I don't want to be restricted to the date format. I just want to search the date field in database like a normal string. So e.g. if I just type in 10, it should show all dates containing "10". Like every entry in october, and every 10th.

Comment: Using date as  a normal string normally return wrong result  if you need a range you should use between clause in where condition .. see  a simple mysql tutorial for this  .. anyway if you want use the query for string be sure of your real archived pattern ..  because 26.01 and 1.10 don't have the same pattern .. you should have always  26.10 or 01.10 .. for this you can use l  where  my_col like ('26.10%')

Answer (score 0):

As mysql datetime (yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS) is reversed to the order of your input data, you would have to make some arrangements. But basically yes, you can treat it as a string. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE `date` LIKE "____-1_-26%"
```

The underscore character acts as a single wildcard - compared to % which acts as possibly multiple wildcard characters.

Furthermore: If your input-data is $input in your PHP environment, you would first break it up into the day-part, month-part and year-part and build your MySql query string from there like thus:

```
"... `date` LIKE "' . $yearpart . '-' . $monthpart . '-' . $daypart . '%"'
```

Having as a starting point

> SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%d.%m.%Y') LIKE '$input'

You would just have to add the % sign after $input. I assume PHP context:

```
'... LIKE "' . $input . '%"'
```

Comment: The entered input is variable. it's not about to find the 26th every time. Here's my attempt:

Comment: SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%d.%m.%Y') LIKE '$input'

Comment: Your attempt is just  missing the % sign immediately after the result of $input. Otherwise it is fine.